# Ruby on rails errors undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below is code extract from my file /home/divya/climb/project1/app/views/cities/new.html.erb where line #5 raised this error:

> undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #5):

```
2: <%= form_for(@city) do |f| %>
3: <%= f.label :country_id %><br />
4: 
5: <%= collection_select(:city, :country_id, @countries, :id, :country_name, {:prompt => false}) %>
6: <%= render 'form' %>
7: 
8: <%= link_to 'Back', cities_path %>

Rails.root: /home/divya/climb/project
```

Answer (score 7):

Apparently you didn't set your `@countries` instance variable in controller, so it is `nil`.
`map` method is called on `@countries` internally by `ActionView` (to be strict, by [`options_from_collection_for_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select) method).

You should set `@countries` in controller, with:

```
@countries = Country.all
```

or call it directly in view:

```
<%= collection_select(:city, :country_id, Country.all, :id, :country_name, { :prompt => false }) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<%= collection_select(:city, :country_id, @countries, :id, :country_name, {:prompt => false}) %>
```

To

```
<%= collection_select(:city, :country_id, Country.all, :id, :country_name, {:prompt => false}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

only change this variable in your controller use a global variable $countries=Country.all and your view use this variable.